# How to switch from one sequence of events to another?

Tags: system.reactive, composition, deferred

I would like that first event to arrive will cause some work. Later I would like to throttle down work a little bit. Until now I came with the following code:

```
var events = Observable.FromEventPattern<...>(...);

var throttled = events.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
events.Take(1).Subscribe((x) =>
{
    DoWork(x);
    throttled.Subscribe((y) => DoWork(y);
});
```

Is there a more elegant way of expressing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's quite simple:

```
var events = Observable.FromEventPattern<...>(...);

var throttled = events.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
events.Take(1).Concat(throttled).Subscribe((x) => DoWork(x));
```

[`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212146%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) will wait for the first sequence to finish and than move subscription to the second.

Answer (score 0):

Another common way is to use select-many. This allows you to pass data from the 1st sequence to the 2nd sequence, it also allows the two sequences to be of different types:

In query comprehension syntax;

```
var q = from x in xs
        from y in ys
        select new {x, y};
```

-or- you can use the standard linq operators as extension methods (losing access to the x value however)

```
xs.SelectMany(x=>ys)
  .Select(y=>y)
```